# Separating hundreds of thousands of points using vba

Tags: performance, vba, excel

My code below takes the following data lines:

```
2017:06:29T14:12:06,0,0,00,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,0,00,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,0,00,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,0,00,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,
2017:06:29T14:12:07,0,1013,02,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,1014,02,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,1015,02,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,1008,02,000,0.000,0.000,000,000,040,040,040,
2017:06:29T14:12:08,0,1013,00,153,-0.102,12.748,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,199,-0.108,12.734,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,171,-0.113,12.741,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,153,-0.114,12.751,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:09,0,1013,00,154,-0.100,12.760,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,200,-0.106,12.732,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,172,-0.112,12.737,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,154,-0.107,12.748,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:10,0,1013,00,155,-0.111,12.744,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,201,-0.105,12.743,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,173,-0.117,12.725,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,155,-0.110,12.739,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:11,0,1013,00,156,-0.112,12.751,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,202,-0.102,12.734,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,174,-0.105,12.755,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,156,-0.110,12.741,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:12,0,1013,00,157,-0.102,12.758,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,203,-0.105,12.744,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,175,-0.103,12.757,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,157,-0.107,12.757,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:13,0,1013,00,158,-0.113,12.737,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,204,-0.094,12.760,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,176,-0.117,12.748,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,158,-0.109,12.744,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:14,0,1013,00,159,-0.103,12.753,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,205,-0.103,12.720,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,177,-0.108,12.732,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,159,-0.110,12.758,000,000,37,35,33,
2017:06:29T14:12:15,0,1013,00,160,-0.112,12.757,000,000,38,34,33,1014,00,206,-0.095,12.734,000,000,38,35,33,1015,00,178,-0.118,12.729,000,000,37,35,33,1008,00,160,-0.115,12.755,000,000,37,35,33,
```

and separates the date and time `2017:06:29T14:12:15`, then rest of the data separated by comas.

As my title says, the data above is only a taste of the actual data that I will be getting. So when I run this code with upto like 10,000 lines of data, excel freezes because the code takes about 7-10 minutes to run.

When I have more than that, excel freezes completely for much longer and when it comes back, the graphs that the code is supposed to generate are missing or inaccurate. I assume this is because there is alot of data but I have no idea how to fix that. I am very new to Excel VBA and I would very much like to learn.

```
Sub SeparateData()
'Purpose:   This macro take the data in the worksheet and separates the data in a readable fashion for the user.
'           This macro also plots and reports any errors that it has caught both in separate sheets named accordingly.

'Define variables
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim k As Variant
Dim data As Variant
Dim data2 As Variant
Dim count As Variant
Dim shiftDown As Variant
Dim monitorNum As Variant
Dim errorCount As Variant
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim plotSheet As Worksheet
Dim errorSheet As Worksheet
Dim battChart As ChartObject
Dim currChart As ChartObject
Dim tempChart As ChartObject


'For code performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Rename the first sheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"
Set dataSheet = Sheets("Data")
'Rename the second sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Plots"
Set plotSheet = Sheets("Plots")
'Rename the third sheet
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Errors"
Set errorSheet = Sheets("Errors")

'Enter the number of monitors
monitorNum = 4

'Variable to shift down the data so that te headers will fit (recommended 2)
shiftDown = 2

'Variable to count the number of errors the program thinks occured
errorCount = 0

'Count how many data point there are in the sheet
count = dataSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.count

'Iterate through the points separating the Data
For i = 0 To count - 1
    'Start of the Data sheet usage
    With dataSheet
    'First separate the date from the rest
    data = .Cells(count - i, 1).Value
    data = Split(data, "T")
    For j = 0 To UBound(data)
        .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, j + 1).Value = data(j)
    Next j
    'Now separate the rest of the data
    data2 = data(1)
    data2 = Split(data2, ",")
    For j = 0 To UBound(data2)
        .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, j + 2).Value = data2(j)
    Next j

    'Check for key switch error
    If .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, 3).Value > 20 Or IsNumeric(.Cells(count - i + shiftDown, 3).Value) = False Then
        'increment the number of errors found
        errorCount = errorCount + 1
        'Save the row number and the monitor number where the error was found
        errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1).Value = "Key switch error in row"
        errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 2).Value = count - i + shiftDown
        errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 3).Value = "in column"
        errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 4).Value = 3
        errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 7).Value = "The recorded data was"
        .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, 3).Copy errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)
        errorSheet.Range(errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1), errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
        'Clear the contents of the error
        .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, 3).ClearContents
    End If

    For k = 0 To monitorNum - 1
        'Check for voltage error
        If .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 8).Value > 20 Or IsNumeric(.Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 8).Value) = False Then
            'increment the number of errors found
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            'Save the row number and the monitor number where the error was found
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1).Value = "Voltage error in row"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 2).Value = count - i + shiftDown
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 3).Value = "in column"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 4).Value = (k * 10) + 8
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 5).Value = "in Monitor"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 6).Value = k + 1
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 7).Value = "The recorded data was"
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 8).Copy errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)
            errorSheet.Range(errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1), errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 160, 180)
            'Clear the contents of the error
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 8).ClearContents
        End If

        'Check for current error
        If .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 7).Value > 80 Or IsNumeric(.Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 7).Value) = False Then
            'increment the number of errors found
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            'Save the row number and the monitor number where the error was found
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1).Value = "Current error in row"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 2).Value = count - i + shiftDown
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 3).Value = "in column"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 4).Value = (k * 10) + 7
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 5).Value = "in Monitor"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 6).Value = k + 1
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 7).Value = "The recorded data was"
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 7).Copy errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)
            errorSheet.Range(errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1), errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 150, 150)
            'Clear the contents of the error
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 7).ClearContents
        End If

        'Check for temperature error
        If .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 13).Value > 83 Or IsNumeric(.Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 13).Value) = False Then
            'increment the number of errors found
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            'Save the row number and the monitor number where the error was found
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1).Value = "Temperature error in row"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 2).Value = count - i + shiftDown
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 3).Value = "in column"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 4).Value = (k * 10) + 13
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 5).Value = "in Monitor"
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 6).Value = k + 1
            errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 7).Value = "The recorded data was"
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 13).Copy errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)
            errorSheet.Range(errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 1), errorSheet.Cells(errorCount, 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            'Clear the contents of the error
            .Cells(count - i + shiftDown, (k * 10) + 13).ClearContents
        End If
    Next k
    'End of Dats sheet usage
    End With
Next i

'The next block uses the Data sheet
With dataSheet

'Erase the data that has been duplicated
For i = 1 To shiftDown
    .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
Next i

'Write and color the headers
'For the Date
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 1), .Cells(shiftDown, 1)).Merge
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 1), .Cells(shiftDown, 1)).Value = "Date"
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 1), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 190, 150)
'For the Time
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 2), .Cells(shiftDown, 2)).Merge
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 2), .Cells(shiftDown, 2)).Value = "Time"
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 2), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 2)).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 140, 80)
'For the Key Switch
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 3), .Cells(shiftDown, 3)).Merge
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 3), .Cells(shiftDown, 3)).Value = "Key Switch"
.Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, 3), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)

For i = 1 To monitorNum
    .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Merge
    .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Value = "Monitor " & i
    'color the headers
    If i Mod 4 = 0 Then
        .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 255, 100)
    ElseIf i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 100, 10)
    ElseIf i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 255)
    Else
        .Range(.Cells(shiftDown - 1, ((i - 1) * 10) + 4), .Cells(shiftDown - 1, (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 75, 75)
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To monitorNum - 1
    'Monitor ID
    .Cells(shiftDown, 1 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "MONITOR_NUM"
    'Monitor status
    .Cells(shiftDown, 2 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "MONITOR_STATUS"
    'Heart Beat count
    .Cells(shiftDown, 3 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "HB_COUNT"
    'For Current
    .Cells(shiftDown, 4 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "CURRENT"
    .Range(.Cells(shiftDown, 4 + (i * 10) + 3), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 4 + (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 150, 150)
    'For Voltage
    .Cells(shiftDown, 5 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "VOLTAGE"
    .Range(.Cells(shiftDown, 5 + (i * 10) + 3), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 5 + (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 160, 180)
    'State of Charge
    .Cells(shiftDown, 6 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "SOC"
    'State of Health
    .Cells(shiftDown, 7 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "SOH"
    'Chip temperature
    .Cells(shiftDown, 8 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "TEMP_CHP"
    'Internal temperature
    .Cells(shiftDown, 9 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "TEMP_INT"
    'For Temperature of the terminal
    .Cells(shiftDown, 10 + (i * 10) + 3).Value = "TEMP_EXT"
    .Range(.Cells(shiftDown, 10 + (i * 10) + 3), .Cells(count + shiftDown, 10 + (i * 10) + 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
Next i

'Data sheet
'Add borders all around the data
.Cells(shiftDown, 1).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
'Autofit all the columns
.Cells(shiftDown, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'End of the Data sheet usage for now
End With

'Error sheet
'Add borders all around the data
errorSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
'Autofit all the columns
errorSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Plotting
'Add a new plot
Set battChart = plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 1200, 300)
'Plot the battery data
With battChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(shiftDown + 5, 8), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, 8))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Battery 1"
    .ChartWizard Title:="Voltage", HasLegend:=True, CategoryTitle:="Time (s)", ValueTitle:="Voltage (V)", Gallery:=xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    For i = 2 To monitorNum
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(5, ((i - 1) * 10) + 8), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, ((i - 1) * 10) + 8))
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = "Battery " & i
    Next i
End With

'Add a new plot
Set currChart = plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 300, 1200, 300)
'Plot the current data
With currChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(shiftDown + 5, 7), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, 7))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Battery 1"
    .ChartWizard Title:="Current", HasLegend:=True, CategoryTitle:="Time (s)", ValueTitle:="Current (A)", Gallery:=xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    For i = 2 To monitorNum
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(5, ((i - 1) * 10) + 7), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, ((i - 1) * 10) + 7))
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = "Battery " & i
    Next i
End With

'Add a new plot
Set tempChart = plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 600, 1200, 300)
'Plot the current data
With tempChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(shiftDown + 5, 13), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, 13))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Battery 1"
    .ChartWizard Title:="Temperature", HasLegend:=True, CategoryTitle:="Time (s)", ValueTitle:="Temperature (F)", Gallery:=xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    For i = 2 To monitorNum
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(5, ((i - 1) * 10) + 13), dataSheet.Cells(count + shiftDown, ((i - 1) * 10) + 13))
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = "Battery " & i
    Next i
End With

'For code performance
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Indicate that the macro has finished its job
Beep

End Sub
```

If there is anything that is unclear or inaccurate, please ask and I will be more than happy to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few items to note and comment on based on the code you've presented. While your code works and you're primarily asking for help on getting it to run faster, other improvements to your code and coding style can only help.

1. The first thing will always be to [use `Option Explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201708021647130995403). Click the link and learn about this, but it's very important and will end up saving you time in the long run.
2. Most of your variables are declared as `Variant`, which does work but doesn't give you or anyone reading your code the idea of what/how those variables are being used. Go ahead and declare them with a type such as `String` or `Long`.
3. Imagine your code into functional sections, then re-partition your code into actual `Sub`s and `Function`s. You have one long routine that takes care of everything, some of which is repetitive. You can save yourself some work by creating functions and make it far more readable. I usually start designing a module or method by "talking" through the steps (mostly just in my head). Those steps become the functions and procedures. Your error logging is a very good example.
4. Make sure to establish an understandable and clear naming convention for your variables, and always set [references to all `Workbooks` and `Worksheets`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201708021647130995403).
5. Some of your variables read more like constants. For example `shiftDown` is always 2. So go ahead and define it as `Const KEY_SWITCH_COL As Long = 3`. A common practice is to use all CAPS to denote a constant value.
6. Try to keep your code lines to about 75-80 characters in width, then use the continuation character to break up the line. This can take practice, but it will make your code far more readable (even for you) and you won't have to scroll side to side.
7. Use descriptive enough variables and you won't have to write comments that explain what the code is obviously doing. But you should definitely write comments that describe a section of the code in more detail. The more the better because these are your "notes" for when you have to come back in six months to understand all this again.
8. The example below will demonstrate this point, but [use a memory array](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3830/work-with-arrays-not-with-ranges#t=201708021647130995403) for this type of data processing. It's far faster than working in and out of the worksheet directly.

So here's a swipe at a top-level reorganization of your code. (I don't understand the details of your logic to cover everything, so please consider this an example.)

```
Public Sub SeparateData()
    SplitRawData
    CheckForErrors
    ApplyFormatting
    CreatePlots
End Sub
```

This sub will get a few more lines, but you see the point.

So while I could have created a class or two (such as an error handler and possibly a class to handle the data), my example keeps everything in one module. The main routine ends up looking like this:

```
Public Sub SeparateData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataWS = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'dataWS.Name = "Data"

    totalErrors = 0

    Dim rawArray As Variant
    rawArray = SplitRawData(dataWS)

    Dim errorWS As Worksheet
    Set errorWS = wb.Sheets("Errors")
    CheckForErrors rawArray, errorWS

    '--- now copy all the split data back to the original worksheet
    '    and overwrite the original data (since we don't need it now)
    '    leave room for header row(s)
    With dataWS
        Const HEADER_COUNT As Long = 1
        Dim destArea As Range
        Set dest = .Range(.Cells(1 + HEADER_COUNT, 1), _
                          .Cells(HEADER_COUNT + UBound(rawArray, 1), UBound(rawArray, 2)))
        dest = rawArray
        '--- put header on worksheet here
    End With

    'ApplyFormatting
    'CreatePlots
End Sub
```

Splitting the data goes tremendously faster if you use an array. The example below parses your data into a memory based array and on my machine processed 20,000 lines in under two seconds.

```
Private Function SplitRawData(ByRef dataWS As Worksheet) As Variant
    '--- unprocessed data is comma delimited CSV. this data must be
    '    split into individual data. for speed, the data will be held
    '    in a memory-based data array and put out to the worksheet later

    '--- assume the data is in a single column, starting in the first row
    '    then pull the raw data into its own array
    Dim lastDataRow As Long
    Dim rawData As Variant
    lastDataRow = dataWS.Cells(dataWS.Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rawData = dataWS.Range("A1").Resize(lastDataRow, 1)

    '--- we need to know how many columns, so count the number of commas
    '    plus one because we'll split the date-time string too
    Dim tempSplit() As String
    Dim totalCols As Long
    tempSplit = Split(rawData(1, 1), ",")
    totalCols = UBound(tempSplit, 1) + 1

    '--- now create the memory array to hold the split raw data. this array
    '    will ultimately be copied back to a worksheet
    Dim splitData() As Variant
    ReDim splitData(1 To lastDataRow, 0 To totalCols)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(splitData, 1)
        '--- cut out the date first
        tempSplit = Split(rawData(i, 1), "T")
        splitData(i, 0) = tempSplit(0)
        '--- now get everything else
        tempSplit = Split(tempSplit(1), ",")
        For j = LBound(tempSplit, 1) To UBound(tempSplit, 1)
            splitData(i, j + 1) = tempSplit(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    '--- return as an array
    SplitRawData = splitData
End Function
```

Similarly, the error checking uses the memory array to go lots faster. Notice that the redundancy of the error logic can be broken out into a single function:

```
Private Sub CheckForErrors(ByRef splitData As Variant, ByRef errorWS As Worksheet)
    '--- examines the data for errors and creates an error log
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(splitData, 1) To UBound(splitData, 1)
        If (splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL) > 20) Or (Not IsNumeric(splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL))) Then
            LogError errorWS, "Key switch error in row", i, KEY_SWITCH_COL, 0, splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL)
        End If

        '--- loop through the columns to check errors for the monitors
        Const TOTAL_MONITORS As Long = 4
        Dim k As Long
        For k = 0 To TOTAL_MONITORS
            '...
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub LogError(ByRef errorWS As Worksheet, _
                     ByVal desc As String, _
                     ByVal rowNum As Long, _
                     ByVal colNum As Long, _
                     ByVal monitorNum As Long, _
                     ByVal recData As Variant, _
                     ByVal errorType As Long)
    Const DESCRIPTION As Long = 1
    Const ROW_NUMBER As Long = 2
    Const COLUMN_TEXT As Long = 3
    Const COLUMN_NUMBER As Long = 4
    Const MONITOR_TEXT As Long = 5
    Const MONITOR_NUMBER As Long = 6
    Const RECORD_TEXT As Long = 7
    Const RECORD_DATA As Long = 8

    With errorWS
        totalErrors = totalErrors + 1
        .Cells(totalErrors, DESCRIPTION) = desc
        .Cells(totalErrors, ROW_NUMBER) = rowNum
        .Cells(totalErrors, COLUMN_TEXT) = "in column"
        .Cells(totalErrors, COLUMN_NUMBER) = colNum
        If monitorNum > 0 Then
            .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_TEXT) = "in monitor"
        Else
            .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_TEXT) = ""
        End If
        .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_NUMBER) = monitorNum
        .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_TEXT) = "The recorded data was"
        .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_DATA) = recData

        Dim thisError As Range
        Set thisError = .Range(.Cells(totalErrors, 1), .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_DATA))
        Select Case errorType
            Case KEY_SWITCH_COL
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
            Case VOLTAGE_OFFSET
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(110, 160, 180)
            Case CURRENT_OFFSET
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(240, 150, 150)
            '... add more as needed ...
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

The remainder of your code can still be separated into helper functions in a similar manner. The caveat there is you won't be able to use a memory array because you're directly formatting worksheet ranges (which doesn't transfer in or out of an array in a block).

Hopefully these examples help, especially with the speed up. But notice how the above discussion points are implemented in the code for readability and maintainability.

---For convenience, here's the whole module in a single block:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const KEY_SWITCH_COL As Long = 3
Private Const VOLTAGE_OFFSET As Long = 8
Private Const CURRENT_OFFSET As Long = 7
Private Const TEMPERATURE_OFFSET As Long = 13

Private totalErrors As Long

Public Sub SeparateData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataWS = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'dataWS.Name = "Data"

    totalErrors = 0

    Dim rawArray As Variant
    rawArray = SplitRawData(dataWS)

    Dim errorWS As Worksheet
    Set errorWS = wb.Sheets("Errors")
    CheckForErrors rawArray, errorWS

    '--- now copy all the split data back to the original worksheet
    '    and overwrite the original data (since we don't need it now)
    '    leave room for header row(s)
    With dataWS
        Const HEADER_COUNT As Long = 1
        Dim destArea As Range
        Set dest = .Range(.Cells(1 + HEADER_COUNT, 1), _
                          .Cells(HEADER_COUNT + UBound(rawArray, 1), UBound(rawArray, 2)))
        dest = rawArray
        '--- put header on worksheet here
    End With

    'ApplyFormatting
    'CreatePlots
End Sub

Private Function SplitRawData(ByRef dataWS As Worksheet) As Variant
    '--- unprocessed data is comma delimited CSV. this data must be
    '    split into individual data. for speed, the data will be held
    '    in a memory-based data array and put out to the worksheet later

    '--- assume the data is in a single column, starting in the first row
    '    then pull the raw data into its own array
    Dim lastDataRow As Long
    Dim rawData As Variant
    lastDataRow = dataWS.Cells(dataWS.Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rawData = dataWS.Range("A1").Resize(lastDataRow, 1)

    '--- we need to know how many columns, so count the number of commas
    '    plus one because we'll split the date-time string too
    Dim tempSplit() As String
    Dim totalCols As Long
    tempSplit = Split(rawData(1, 1), ",")
    totalCols = UBound(tempSplit, 1) + 1

    '--- now create the memory array to hold the split raw data. this array
    '    will ultimately be copied back to a worksheet
    Dim splitData() As Variant
    ReDim splitData(1 To lastDataRow, 0 To totalCols)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(splitData, 1)
        '--- cut out the date first
        tempSplit = Split(rawData(i, 1), "T")
        splitData(i, 0) = tempSplit(0)
        '--- now get everything else
        tempSplit = Split(tempSplit(1), ",")
        For j = LBound(tempSplit, 1) To UBound(tempSplit, 1)
            splitData(i, j + 1) = tempSplit(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    '--- return as an array
    SplitRawData = splitData
End Function

Private Sub CheckForErrors(ByRef splitData As Variant, ByRef errorWS As Worksheet)
    '--- examines the data for errors and creates an error log
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(splitData, 1) To UBound(splitData, 1)
        If (splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL) > 20) Or (Not IsNumeric(splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL))) Then
            LogError errorWS, "Key switch error in row", i, KEY_SWITCH_COL, 0, splitData(i, KEY_SWITCH_COL)
        End If

        '--- loop through the columns to check errors for the monitors
        Const TOTAL_MONITORS As Long = 4
        Dim k As Long
        For k = 0 To TOTAL_MONITORS
            '...
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub LogError(ByRef errorWS As Worksheet, _
                     ByVal desc As String, _
                     ByVal rowNum As Long, _
                     ByVal colNum As Long, _
                     ByVal monitorNum As Long, _
                     ByVal recData As Variant, _
                     ByVal errorType As Long)
    Const DESCRIPTION As Long = 1
    Const ROW_NUMBER As Long = 2
    Const COLUMN_TEXT As Long = 3
    Const COLUMN_NUMBER As Long = 4
    Const MONITOR_TEXT As Long = 5
    Const MONITOR_NUMBER As Long = 6
    Const RECORD_TEXT As Long = 7
    Const RECORD_DATA As Long = 8

    With errorWS
        totalErrors = totalErrors + 1
        .Cells(totalErrors, DESCRIPTION) = desc
        .Cells(totalErrors, ROW_NUMBER) = rowNum
        .Cells(totalErrors, COLUMN_TEXT) = "in column"
        .Cells(totalErrors, COLUMN_NUMBER) = colNum
        If monitorNum > 0 Then
            .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_TEXT) = "in monitor"
        Else
            .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_TEXT) = ""
        End If
        .Cells(totalErrors, MONITOR_NUMBER) = monitorNum
        .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_TEXT) = "The recorded data was"
        .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_DATA) = recData

        Dim thisError As Range
        Set thisError = .Range(.Cells(totalErrors, 1), .Cells(totalErrors, RECORD_DATA))
        Select Case errorType
            Case KEY_SWITCH_COL
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
            Case VOLTAGE_OFFSET
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(110, 160, 180)
            Case CURRENT_OFFSET
                thisError.Interior.Color = RGB(240, 150, 150)
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: One minor note, I strongly prefer declaring arrays as `Dim SomeArray as Variant` versus `Dim SomeArray() as Variant`. There are some unique cases where a `Variant()` causes an issue while a `Variant` doesn't (and rarely does a `Variant` open up your code to errors that `Variant()` wouldnt be vulnerable to).

Comment: Hello Peter. I thank you for the effort and your help. What I do not like about this code is that making multiple separate sections would actually make it confusing for a code size like this. I won't say that I am an experienced coder, but I have found it just a little bit confusing to follow your code

Answer (score 1):

My approach uses Excel's TextToColumns to split the data and Conditional Formatting instead of formatting the individual cells on the Error worksheet.  I also replaced the row and column numbers on the Error worksheet with a cell address and hyperlink to the error.

Using these techniques I was able to process 20,000 rows, adding the 3 Charts and logging 7200+ errors (that I added to the data) in 16.13 seconds.  Processing the data itself took 1.18 second.

### Execution Time

[image: Execution Time]

### Data Worksheets

[image: Data Worksheets]

### Charts

The Charts displayed fine with a smaller dataset but 20,000 rows didn't display properly.

[image: Charts]

### Error Worksheet

[image: Error Worksheet]

Note: Conditional Formatting is not only faster, then making a large number of individual formatted cells, but will reduce the overall file size.

```
Option Explicit
Enum MonitorColumns
    mcMONITOR_NUM = 1
    mcMONITOR_STATUS
    mcHB_COUNT
    mcCURRENT
    mcVOLTAGE
    mcSOC
    mcSOH
    mcTEMP_CHP
    mcTEMP_INT
    mcTEMP_EXT
    mcCOUNT = 10
End Enum

Enum ErrorType
    etCurrent = 1
    etKeySwitch
    etTempature
    etVoltage
End Enum

Sub CalculateRunTime_Seconds()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many seconds it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
'https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

'*****************************
ProcessData
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation, "ProcessData"

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessData()
    Const MonitorCount = 4
    Dim TopLeftCell As Range
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, plotSheet As Worksheet, errorSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Rename Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Data": Set dataSheet = Sheets("Data")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Plots": Set plotSheet = Sheets("Plots")
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Errors": Set errorSheet = Sheets("Errors")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set TopLeftCell = dataSheet.Range("A1")
    SplitData TopLeftCell.CurrentRegion
    dataSheet.Rows("1:2").Insert

    Set TopLeftCell = dataSheet.Range("A1")           'Reset TopLeftCell
    FormatData TopLeftCell, MonitorCount
    Set TopLeftCell = dataSheet.Range("A1")           'Reset TopLeftCell

    AddChartDetails plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 1200, 300), TopLeftCell, MonitorCount, mcVOLTAGE, "Voltage", "Voltage (V)"
    AddChartDetails plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 300, 1200, 300), TopLeftCell, MonitorCount, mcCURRENT, "Current", "Current (A)"
    AddChartDetails plotSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 600, 1200, 300), TopLeftCell, MonitorCount, mcTEMP_EXT, "Temperature", "Temperature (F)"

    SetupErrorSheet errorSheet
    FindErrors TopLeftCell, MonitorCount, errorSheet

    'Add Borders
    dataSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    errorSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    'AutoFit Columns
    dataSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    errorSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub

Private Sub SplitData(Source As Range)
    Source.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                         TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                         Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
                         "T", _
                         TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub

Private Sub FormatData(TopLeftCell As Range, MonitorCount As Long)
    Const HEADER As String = "MONITOR_NUM|MONITOR_STATUS|HB_COUNT|CURRENT|VOLTAGE|SOC|SOH|TEMP_CHP|TEMP_INT|TEMP_EXT"
    Dim data As Variant, MonitorColor As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MonitorTopLeftCell As Range

    Set MonitorTopLeftCell = TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 3)
    data = Split(HEADER, "|")
    For i = 1 To MonitorCount
        With MonitorTopLeftCell
            '2nd Row
            .Offset(1).Resize(1, UBound(data) + 1) = data
            'Format Header Row
            .Range("G2").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 150, 150)    'CURRENT
            .Range("H2").Interior.Color = RGB(110, 160, 180)    'VOLTAGE
            .Range("J2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)    'TEMP_EXT
            '1st Row
            .Value = "Monitor " & i
            With .Resize(1, UBound(data) + 1)
                .Merge
                .Interior.Color = Choose((i Mod 4) + 1, RGB(100, 255, 100), RGB(255, 75, 75), RGB(100, 100, 255), RGB(255, 100, 10))
            End With
        End With
        Set MonitorTopLeftCell = MonitorTopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Next

    With TopLeftCell
        .Range("A2:C2").Value = Array("Date", "Time", "Key Switch")
        .Range("A1:A2").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 190, 150)
        .Range("B1:B2").Interior.Color = RGB(150, 140, 80)
        .Range("C1:C2").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
        'Paint Formats accross all rows
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy
        Range(TopLeftCell.Offset(1), TopLeftCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    'Iterate Backwards becuase TopLeftCell becomes nothing after it is merged
    For i = 2 To 0 Step -1
        TopLeftCell.Range("A1:A2").Offset(0, i).Merge
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub AddChartDetails(MyChart As ChartObject, TopLeftCell As Range, MonitorCount As Long, MonitorCol As MonitorColumns, Title As String, ValueTitle As String)
    Dim i As Long
    With MyChart.chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, 1, MonitorCol)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Battery 1"
        .ChartWizard Title:=Title, HasLegend:=True, CategoryTitle:="Time (s)", ValueTitle:=ValueTitle, Gallery:=xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        For i = 2 To MonitorCount
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(i).Values = getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, i, MonitorCol)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Name = "Battery " & i
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Function getMonitorData(TopLeftCell As Range, MonitorNumber As Long, MonitorCol As MonitorColumns) As Range
    Const DATAROWOFFSET As Long = 4
    Dim Offset As Long
    Offset = (MonitorColumns.mcCOUNT * (MonitorNumber - 1)) + MonitorCol + 2
    Set getMonitorData = Range(TopLeftCell.Offset(DATAROWOFFSET), TopLeftCell.Offset(DATAROWOFFSET).End(xlDown)).Offset(0, Offset)
End Function

Private Sub FindErrors(TopLeftCell As Range, MonitorCount As Long, errorSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cell In getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, 1, MonitorColumns.mcMONITOR_NUM - 1)    'RGB(200, 200, 0)
        If cell.Value > 20 Or IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False Then LogError cell, ErrorType.etKeySwitch, errorSheet, i
    Next

    For i = 1 To MonitorCount
        For Each cell In getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, i, MonitorColumns.mcCURRENT)    'RGB(240, 150, 150)
            If cell.Value > 80 Or IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False Then LogError cell, ErrorType.etCurrent, errorSheet, i, cell.Offset(0, MonitorColumns.mcMONITOR_NUM - MonitorColumns.mcCURRENT).Value
        Next

        For Each cell In getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, i, MonitorColumns.mcTEMP_EXT)    'RGB(255, 190, 0)
            If cell.Value > 83 Or IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False Then LogError cell, ErrorType.etTempature, errorSheet, i, cell.Offset(0, MonitorColumns.mcMONITOR_NUM - MonitorColumns.mcTEMP_EXT).Value
        Next

        For Each cell In getMonitorData(TopLeftCell, i, MonitorColumns.mcVOLTAGE)    'RGB(110, 160, 180)
            If cell.Value > 20 Or IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False Then LogError cell, ErrorType.etVoltage, errorSheet, i, cell.Offset(0, MonitorColumns.mcMONITOR_NUM - MonitorColumns.mcVOLTAGE).Value
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Function LogError(cell As Range, Category As ErrorType, errorSheet As Worksheet, MonitorNumber As Long, Optional MONITOR_NUM As Long)
    Dim SubAddress As String
    Dim Offset As Long

    SubAddress = "'" & cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(False, False)
    With errorSheet
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Range("A1").Value = Choose(Category, "Current", "Key Switch", "Tempature", "Voltage")
            .Range("D1").Value = cell.Value
            If Category <> etKeySwitch Then
                .Range("B1").Value = MonitorNumber
                If MONITOR_NUM > 0 Then .Range("C1").Value = MONITOR_NUM
            End If

            errorSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("E1"), Address:="", SubAddress:=SubAddress, TextToDisplay:=cell.Address
        End With
    End With
    cell.ClearContents
End Function

Sub SetupErrorSheet(errorSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long
    errorSheet.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Error", "Monitor", "Monitor Number", "Value", "Hyperlnk")
    With errorSheet.Columns(1)
        For i = 1 To 4
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""" & Choose(i, "Key Switch", "Current", "Tempature", "Voltage") & """"
            With .FormatConditions(i).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = Choose(i, RGB(200, 200, 0), RGB(240, 150, 150), RGB(255, 190, 0), RGB(110, 160, 180))
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Kudos to @PeterT for his excellent documentation and answer.  I recommend reviewing his thought process on how to refactor your could.  He was spot on.

Comment: Try running this on a few hundred thousand lines, purely because of the title of the OP. While this may be efficient for a smaller set (20k rows is fairly inconsequential) I am curious to see how your solution fares with 300k, or even half a million lines.

Comment: Also, please consider breaking up your individual subs into their own code blocks. I thought your code was one large sub until I saw the sub's within the code. It can be difficult for someone to follow along in this format though.

Comment: @BrandonBarney my code broke running the data with 200K rows because Excel cannot have more than 655535 Hyperlinks per sheet.  Without handling hyperlinks the code processed 200K rows in 39 seconds on a slow computer.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I might consider breaking up the code further but I don't have time.

Comment: Does the original code include Hyperlinks? I tried doing a `CTRL+F` to see, but I dont know the accuracy of that with code formatting. If hyperlinks aren't part of the original, you may want to consider allowing the user to select an option to include them or not (as a precaution if this project were to scale larger for the OP). Otherwise though, 39 seconds is quite impressive for 200k rows. I would've assumed that with a scale in complexity you would encounter a much faster increase in processing time.

Comment: One last bit, be sure to properly (and fully) qualify `Sheets` references. Depending on the OP's usage, you could encounter an issue if `Sheets` is not actually intended to be used with `ActiveWorkbook`. I strongly prefer either `ThisWorkbook` or declaring a variable and opening the target workbook.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for replying. If you could figure out the graph issue, this code would be worth more than gold to me

Comment: @Vik I don't work with charts very often.  You should see if you can get help on StackOverflow.  You might want to provide a download link for a workbook with sample data and charts.